# Why can the gurgling sound of water only be heard when it's disappeared down a drain, and not before?

Tags: water, drain, sink

In lots of sinks that I've used, I've noticed that the water makes a gurgling sound when it has all disappeared down the drain - however, the gurgling sound can only be heard after all of the water has gone - it's not noticeable when the sink tap is still running. Why can the gurgling sound only be heard when all of the water has disappeared - and not before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens on direct vented fixtures that have no actual vent; they're close enough to the stack (<5') not to need one.

And when there's a 'head' of water above the trap while the water's running, there's too much suction to let any air in, so it pulls air down the stack. Once it has less 'head' **it's easier to pull air past the water in the trap then it is to pull it down the stack**. : *gurgle gurgle*

Basically, when water travels down a vented pipe, it creates an air pressure differential. The make-up air will take the path of least resistance. Be that, pushing a little bit of water out of the trap to make an air gap, or pulling it all the way back down from the roof.

Comment: *How to not get upvotes on Diy.SE* : answer physics questions on a Sunday night....